# Ebay API: ActiveInventoryReport data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, ebay-api, google-sheets-formula

I want to import ActiveInventoryReport data into google sheet.
So I was going to use "https://webservices.ebay.com/BulkDataExchangeService".
I want to know how to make headers and how to make import it into google sheet.
I don't know about ebay api so it is difficult to import data for me.
Please help me, if you know about that.
I tried to get it using following code:

```
var request = 'http://webservices.ebay.com/BulkDataExchangeService';
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-"?>\
<ActiveInventoryReportRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">\
  <RequesterCredentials>\
    <eBayAuthToken></eBayAuthToken>\
  </RequesterCredentials>\
  <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>\
  <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>\
</ActiveInventoryReportRequest>';

var headers = {
'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
'X-EBAY-API-SITEID': '0',
'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL': '967',
'X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME' : 'startDownloadJob',
'X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-TOKEN': '',
'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME': 'ActiveInventoryReport'
};

var options = {
method: 'POST',
headers: headers,
payload: xml
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(request, options).getContentText();
Logger.log(response);
```

Comment: Can you provide the document about the API and the method of the API you want to use?

Comment: These are the documents to reference. https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/merchant-data/CallRef/ActiveInventoryReport.html  and https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/large-merchant-services/Concepts/MakingACall.html

Comment: Thank you for replying. It seems that the headers and payload in your script are correct for UrlFetchApp. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) But I cannot confirm whether the values of headers and payload including your token can be used for the endpoint. Can I ask you about your issue?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I want to know : first,how to get ActiveInventoryReport data from eBay and second, how to import the data into googlesheet. I studied ActiveInventoryReport api, but I can't know how to make api call to get ActiveInventoryReport data exactly. So if someone knows it, please let me know exactly. (It would be better if I can get exact code)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the issue of your script? Can you provide the response value from your script when an error occurs? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have ebay auth taken and I didn't test my code. So I am looking for someone who help me to test it or who has good experience in this filed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that I couldn't notice about your situation.